# Looking for open-source library for editing AAC metadata (M4A files)

Tags: open-source, audio, aac, m4a

I'm looking for an open-source library for editing AAC metadata in M4A files (as appearing in iTunes).  Specifically, I need to be able to add an album art tag.  It should be something similar to id3lib, which works with ID3 tags on MP3 files.

Answer (score 5):

Try looking at [mp4v2](//github.com/svnpenn/mp4v2).  Although the code base is rather large and may be difficult to integrate into your build system, the library provides some command-line executables that you can use to modify AAC tags, including artwork.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since I hadn't find any open-source library maybe open-source program, that can read and set iTunes-style metadata tags in MPEG-4 files, will help you.
[atomicparsley.sourceforge.net](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/)

There is also Known iTunes Metadata structure provided: http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/mpeg-4files.html

This discussion may also turn out helpful for you: [www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/lofiversion/index.php/t31022.html](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/lofiversion/index.php/t31022.html)

Good Luck